# How can I make Qt use a user-defined class?

Tags: windows-10, qt5, qt-creator, qplaintextedit, custom-widgets

I'd like to user a user-defined class rather Qt's generated in the `Ui_MainWindow` class so that I can use that control on Qt's GUI Designer. For example, currently it's defined as this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QPlainTextEdit *list;
 // ...
};
```

I'd like to use my user-defined class:

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    MyCustomQPlainTextEdit *list;
 // ...
};
```

I cannot just modify it by hand in the ui_mainwindow.h header file because  that value will be lost every time the GUI designer generate its metadata.
Can I prevent Qt to use that class so that I can use my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `MyCustomQPlainTextEdit` inherits from `QPlainTextEdit` you can "promote" the widget in your ui file to your custom class.

Open your ui file in Qt Creator, right click the widget and select `Promote To`

[[image: enter image description here]]

Then in the dialog that opens up, add your custom class like so:

[[image: enter image description here]]

Be sure to alter the path to the header file if needed depending on how your project is set up. Then click `Add`.

After you custom class has been added, click `Promote` and voila, your custom class in the generated `ui_<blah>.h`.

Comment: Awesome!! So easy. I was a bit hopeless whether Qt creator could have a feature for this, I was afraid of doing hacks to archive that :)

Comment: @Jack Qt Creator can do quite a bit actually; really useful for visual design of your UI. Have fun!